# Creating quickview with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create quick view for a shopping cart,

Problem 1: When I Place my mouse over any of the boxes, quickview appears on all the box, how can I display it only in parent node.

Problem 2: When I place my mouse on quickview link, it keeps on toggling .

Here is my code

```
<html>
<title>Quick view </title>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.quickview{
    margin:0px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:18%;
    margin-left:12%;
    border:1px;
    border-color:red;
    border-style:dotted;
    display:none;
}

.box{
    margin:10px;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border:2px;
    border-color:green;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:silver;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".box").bind('mouseover',function(event){
                        $(".quickview").stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
        });
                $(".box").bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
                        $(".quickview").stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
        });
    });
        </script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:10px;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <TD>
            <div class="quickview">
                <a href="doo.php">Quick View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="foo.php">

                </a>
            </div>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <div class="quickview">
                <a href="doo.php">Quick View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="foo.php">

                </a>
            </div>
        </TD>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TD>
            <div class="quickview">
                <a href="doo.php">Quick View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="foo.php">

                </a>
            </div>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <div class="quickview">
                <a href="doo.php">Quick View</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="foo.php">

                </a>
            </div>
        </TD>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 $(".box").bind('mouseenter',function(event){
     $(this).prev(".quickview").stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
 }).parent().bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
     $(this).find(".quickview").stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
 });​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8gX/2/)

Comment: @Rkumaram You're welcome.If this is *correct for you*, then you probably could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.